# Spring boot integration test not executing initialization steps inside application main method

Tags: java, spring-boot, integration-testing, jhipster, liquibase

The ServerApp's main method has a method to initialize service. It works fine when running inside IDE but fails to run when running the integration test. How to make the test work? Is there anything more that can be improved about the test?

**ServerApp**

```
@SpringBootApplication
@EnableConfigurationProperties({LiquibaseProperties.class, ApplicationProperties.class})
public class ServerApp {

 @PostConstruct
    public void initApplication() {
//... 
}

 public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication app = new SpringApplication(ServerApp.class);
        DefaultProfileUtil.addDefaultProfile(app);
        applicationContext  = app.run(args);
        Environment env = applicationContext.getEnvironment();
//...
applicationContext.getBean(BalanceService.class).init(); // <<< this one
    }
```

Test

```
@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)
@SpringBootTest(webEnvironment = SpringBootTest.WebEnvironment.MOCK, classes = ServerApp.class)
@AutoConfigureMockMvc
public class BalanceResourceIntTest {

private static final String DEFAULT_USERNAME = "playerTEST";

private static final UUID TRANSACTION_UUID_ONE = UUID.fromString("336ca9de-1583-4f39-9c67-f8380323d09d");
private static final UUID TRANSACTION_UUID_TWO = UUID.fromString("4a14ca32-a952-11e8-98d0-529269fb1459");

private static final BigDecimal INITIAL_BALANCE = new BigDecimal(3);
private static final BigDecimal BALANCE_CHANGE = new BigDecimal(2);
private static final BigDecimal BALANCE_AFTER_CHANGE = new BigDecimal(5);

private static final Long DEFAULT_BALANCE_VERSION = 1L;
private static final Long UPDATED_BALANCE_VERSION = 2L;

private final Logger log = LoggerFactory.getLogger(BalanceResourceIntTest.class);

@Autowired
private MappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter jacksonMessageConverter;

@Autowired
private ExceptionTranslator exceptionTranslator;

@Autowired
private PageableHandlerMethodArgumentResolver pageableArgumentResolver;

@Autowired
private EntityManager em;

@Autowired
private TransactionService transactionService;

@Autowired
private PlayerRepository playerRepository;

private MockMvc restBalanceMockMvc;

private Player player;

private Transaction transaction;

@Before
public void setup() {
    MockitoAnnotations.initMocks(this);
    final BalanceResource balanceResource = new BalanceResource(transactionService);
    this.restBalanceMockMvc = MockMvcBuilders.standaloneSetup(balanceResource)
        .setCustomArgumentResolvers(pageableArgumentResolver)
        .setControllerAdvice(exceptionTranslator)
        .setConversionService(createFormattingConversionService())
        .setMessageConverters(jacksonMessageConverter).build();
}


public static Transaction createTransaction() {
    Transaction transaction = new Transaction();
    transaction.setUsername(DEFAULT_USERNAME);
    transaction.setTransactionId(TRANSACTION_UUID_ONE);
    transaction.setBalanceChange(BALANCE_CHANGE);
    return transaction;
}

public static Player createEntity(EntityManager em) {
    Player player = new Player()
        .username(DEFAULT_USERNAME)
        .balanceVersion(DEFAULT_BALANCE_VERSION)
        .balance(INITIAL_BALANCE);
    return player;
}


@Before
public void initTest() {
    player = createEntity(em);
    transaction = createTransaction();
}


@Test
@Transactional
public void updatePlayer() throws Exception {


    playerRepository.saveAndFlush(player);

    int databaseSizeBeforeUpdate = playerRepository.findAll().size();

    // Update the player

    log.debug("transaction: {}", transaction);

    restBalanceMockMvc.perform(put("/api/balance")
        .contentType(TestUtil.APPLICATION_JSON_UTF8)
        .content(TestUtil.convertObjectToJsonBytes(transaction)))
        .andExpect(status().isOk())
        .andExpect(jsonPath("$.[*].transactionId").value(hasItem(TRANSACTION_UUID_ONE)))
        .andExpect(jsonPath("$.[*].errorCode").value(hasItem("")))
        .andExpect(jsonPath("$.[*].balanceVersion").value(hasItem(UPDATED_BALANCE_VERSION.intValue())))
        .andExpect(jsonPath("$.[*].balanceChange").value(hasItem(BALANCE_CHANGE))) // intValue?
        .andExpect(jsonPath("$.[*].balance").value(hasItem(BALANCE_AFTER_CHANGE.intValue())));

    Thread.sleep(BalanceService.INIT_DELAY_OF_SCHEDULER + BalanceService.DELAY_BETWEEN_SCHEDULED_JOBS);

    // Validate the Player in the database
    List<Player> playerList = playerRepository.findAll();
    assertThat(playerList).hasSize(databaseSizeBeforeUpdate);
    Player testPlayer = playerList.get(playerList.size() - 1);
    assertThat(testPlayer.getUsername()).isEqualTo(DEFAULT_USERNAME);
    assertThat(testPlayer.getBalanceVersion()).isEqualTo(UPDATED_BALANCE_VERSION);
    assertThat(testPlayer.getBalance()).isEqualTo(BALANCE_AFTER_CHANGE);
}
```

}

The test fails with:

```
java.lang.AssertionError: Status 
Expected :200
Actual   :500
```

There is no debug information in console what causes 500 error on serverside.

Answer (score 0):

Internal Error 500

*The server encountered an unexpected condition which prevented it from fulfilling the request.*

The 500 Internal Server Error is the general catch all error when the server throws an exception. It is the error message when no more specific error message is suitable. It may be difficult to troubleshoot this error because it can be triggered out by many different issues. One common cause of this error is scripting issues such as a form fails to handle a missing or incorrect value correctly. Various server faults can also cause this error like a failed disk or nonfunctional software module. Simply, the 500 Internal Server Error is a general http status code that means something has gone wrong on the website’s server, but the server could not be more specific on what that exact problem is.